# SELECT max(date) return the latest record but the wrong data

Tags: select, maxdate

I have multiple records **all with the same** `user_id` and each with its unique `TIMESTAMP`.

I need to return the correct data for a `user_id` based on the latest date - `MAX(date)`.

My query returns the last date *but* the incorrect data (ie Data associated with a previous record-set):

```
    SELECT user_id, doc_docpath_00, max(doc_uploadtimestamp) FROM doc
    WHERE user_id = '90';
```

Could you help me understanding how to correct my query?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can work that way.

I believe you should try something like:

```
select user_id, doc_docpath_00
from doc
where user_id = '90' and doc_uploadtimestamp = (
    select max(doc_uploadtimestamp)
    from doc where user_id = '90');
```

Comment: Yes. But be aware that nested queries can be abominably slow in at least mySql. Faced with similar I wrote two separate queries in the application language, one to extract the max() and the other to feed that back into a new queries where clause. Far faster and far less memory on BIG tables